# php vs. php-fpm version mismatch after upgrade

Tags: php, nginx

I was running a custombuild directadmin configuration with PHP 5.4 and Nginx.
First I was trying to upgrade PHP to 5.6 via yum, but I had no luck.
Later on someone told me I have to upgrade via custombuild.
So I rebuild everything.

PHP -v will give me version 5.6, but php-fpm -v still stuck at version 5.4.

I'm running selfhosted CRM system (build in codeigniter) that uses some php-fpm forwarders inside nginx.conf and the software keeps complaining I'm in php version 5.4.
When I place a phpinfo() in the directory of that software, it shows me also that php is in version 5.6.

So it looks to me that it has to do with php-fpm version.
How can I upgrade it to 5.6?

Comment: When you compiled PHP 5.6, it probably built php-fpm along with it. But your nginx is not referencing the new one. What is the path of the newly compiled PHP 5.6? Do `which php` and then `which php-fpm`.  It may be as simple as pointing nginx to the path of the new php-fpm.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php & /usr/sbin/php-fpm Any idea where it is specified inside nginx?

Comment: Initially it may not be that nginx needs different instructions, but rather that the process starting php-fpm does. How do you normally start php-fpm? Ubuntu for example, provides `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` and if that's what started it, it may not have the right path.  Looking at one of my installs, the `PATH=` in that file doesn't include `/usr/local/sbin`. First, find out where your new `php-fpm` is. If you installed to `/usr/local`, then it may be at `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm`.  Then you will need to make a change to how it is started. Maybe by making a copy of the init script...

Comment: ... as something like `/etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm` and make sure your system can start it as a service.

Comment: If I need to restart php-fpm I do "service php-fpm restart" but that starts the old one

Comment: Okay, so try what I suggested - make a copy of /etc/init.d/php-fpm and modify it to use the newly compiled one (maybe /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm) once you've located it.  Don't modify the original, because your OS will overwrite it with updates.